# Error with beautiful soup: list index out of range

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib

I'm a **very new programmer to python.  Working on a webcrawler using urllib and beautifulsoup.  Please ignore the while loop at the top and incrementation of i, I'm just running this test version, and for one page, but it will eventually include a whole set.  My problem is that this gets the soup, but generates an error.  I'm not sure that I'm collecting the table data correctly, but I hope that this code can ignore the  links and just write the text to a .csv file.  For now I'm focused on just printing the text to the screen correctly.

```
line 17, in <module>
    uspc = col[0].string
IndexError: list index out of range
```

HERE is the code:

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

i=125
while i==125:
    url = "http://www.uspto.gov/web/patents/classification/cpc/html/us" + str(i) + "tocpc.html"
    print url + '\n'
    i += 1
    data = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
    print data
    #get the table data from dump
    #append to csv file
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
    table = soup.find("table", width='80%')
    for row in table.findAll('tr')[1:]:
        col = row.findAll('td')
        uspc = col[0].string
        cpc1 = col[1].string
        cpc2 = col[2].string
        cpc3 = col[3].string
        record = (uspc, cpc1, cpc2, cpc3)
        print "|".join(record)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Beautifulsoup for row loop only runs once?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15908604/beautifulsoup-for-row-loop-only-runs-once)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I solved this problem by changing the following line:

```
for row in table.findAll('tr')[1:]:
```

to:

```
for row in table.findAll('tr')[2:]:
```

the error was because the first row of the table had split columns