# Beautifulsoup for row loop only runs once?

Tags: python, loops, beautifulsoup

I'm almost finished a webcralwer grabbing a table.  This outputs the first row in the table only.  Can anyone help identify why this does not return all rows in the table.  Please ignore the while loop as this will eventually have a looped section.

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#file_name = "/user/joe/uspc-cpc.txt
#file = open(file_name,"w")
i=125
while i==125:
    url = "http://www.uspto.gov/web/patents/classification/cpc/html/us" + str(i) + "tocpc.html"
    print url + '\n'
    i += 1
    data = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
    print data
    #get the table data from dump
    #append to csv file
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
    table = soup.find("table", width='80%')
    for tr in table.findAll('tr')[2:]:
        col = row.findAll('td')
        uspc = col[0].get_text().encode('ascii','ignore')
        cpc1 = col[1].get_text().encode('ascii','ignore')
        cpc2 = col[2].get_text().encode('ascii','ignore')
        cpc3 = col[3].get_text().encode('ascii','ignore')
        print uspc + ',' + cpc1 + ',' + cpc2 + ',' + cpc3 + '\n'
        #file.write(record)

#file.close()
```

CODE I'm running:

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#file_name = "/users/ripple/uspc-cpc.txt"
#file = open(file_name,"w")
i=125
while i==125:
    url = "http://www.uspto.gov/web/patents/classification/cpc/html/us" + str(i) + "tocpc.html"
    print 'Grabbing from: ' + url + '\n'
    i += 1
    #get the table data from the page
    data = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
    #send to beautiful soup
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
    table = soup.find("table", width='80%')
    for tr in table.findAll('tr')[2:]:
        col = tr.findAll('td')

        uspc = col[0].get_text().encode('ascii','ignore').replace(" ","")
        cpc1 = col[1].get_text().encode('ascii','ignore').replace(" ","")
        cpc2 = col[2].get_text().encode('ascii','ignore').replace(" ","")
        cpc3 = col[3].get_text().encode('ascii','ignore').replace(" ","").replace("more...", "")
        record = uspc + ',' + cpc1 + ',' + cpc2 + ',' + cpc3 + '\n'
        print record
        #file.write(record)

#file.close()
```

Comment: You don't have `row` defined.

Comment: @Marjin Pieters: How can I define row?  The output is one row: 125/901,H 03H 3/02,B 28D 5/00,H 03H 3/04,B 23D 47/005,B 24B 37/08more...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `tr` as a loop variable, but refer to `row` instead in the loop. If you had `row` defined before it'll probably produce confusing results.

```
for tr in table.findAll('tr')[2:]:
    col = tr.findAll('td')
```

works for me:

```
125/1,B 28D 1/00,B 28D 1/221,E 01C 23/081,B 28D 1/005,B 28D 1/06more...

125/2,B 23Q 35/10,B 22C 9/18,B 23B 5/162,B 23D 63/18,B 24B 53/07more...

125/3,B 28D 1/18,B 28D 1/003,B 28D 1/048,B 28D 1/181,B 24B 7/22more...
```

etc.

Comment: I changed both to tr.  I still only get one row printed.

Comment: @JosephLee: not with the code you posted. It works for me with the one correction I made.

Comment: so strange.  I still only get one line of code printed. after the soup is printed out.  It's the last row though... so I'm not sure what to think about that... 125/901,H03H3/02,B28D5/00,H03H3/04,B23D47/005,B24B37/08

Comment: I uncommented the writing to file option and still only get one line of output in the file.  It's the last line of the table

Comment: @Joseph Lee Please post the whole code. I have a feeling there is something different in your code from the one you provided here.

Comment: @IonutHulub I reposted the code Im running to the question area.  I tried adding a simple print 'hi' to the empty line of code and it prints it out many times... so strange.

Comment: I see you accepted the answer. Plase explain why you could only see the last line and how you fixed that.

Comment: For some strange reason it seems that textwrangler, the text editor I am using was indenting wrong.  That's all I can think of because, after I copied the text to texteditor, and then pasted it back into a new textwrangler file, it worked.  He was right that my variable was defined incorrectly, but that in the end was not the only issue, strangely.  Thanks for your help!